# ArcGIS for Windows Phone with Bing maps and shapefiles

Tags: bing-maps, windows-phone

I have a set of shapefiles that I want to display on a map along with satellite imagery.

I currently use ThinkGeo for this sort of thing on Windows.

I'm writing a Windows Phone app that must operate in offline mode and ThinkGeo do not yet have a Windows Phone product.

I think I have 2 choices:

1. Use ArcGIS for Windows Phone. Use Bing maps imagery when online. Store the shapefiles offline.
2. Use Bing maps and try to draw the shapefiles onto it or generate tiles from the shape files.

Has anyone gone down this road? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There have been a lot of discussions about offline support on the ESRI Forums, so I would suggest that you checkout the development on the [betacommunity](http://betacommunity.esri.com) as for shape files there is a [Contrib](http://esrislcontrib.codeplex.com/) package for Silverlight that includes a Shapefile datasource might be possible to convert to WP7.